# PowerShell error : Cannot Invoke this function because the current host does not implement it

Tags: c#, powershell

```
function LogMe() {
    Param(
        [parameter(Mandatory = $true, ValueFromPipeline = $true)]$logEntry,
        [switch]$display,
        [switch]$error,
        [switch]$warning,
        [switch]$progress
    )

    if ($error) {
        $logEntry = "[ERROR] $logEntry"
        Write-Host "$logEntry" -ForegroundColor Red
    } elseif ($warning) {
        Write-Warning "$logEntry"
        $logEntry = "[WARNING] $logEntry"
    } elseif ($progress) {
        Write-Host "$logEntry" -ForegroundColor Green
    } elseif ($display) {
        Write-Host "$logEntry"
    }

    #$logEntry = ((Get-Date -uformat "%D %T") + " - " + $logEntry)
    $logEntry | -force Out-File $logFile -Append
}
```

The above code spits out an error described in the title. I tried `-force` any other suggestions?

It's not C# per se but the error I'm getting is coming from C# when I run using `pipeline.invoke`.

Comment: What does this have to do with C#? Please only use relevant tags.

Comment: We'd need the relevent bits from the error too, like what line and command throws the error...

Comment: @itsme86 Are you sure that [C#] not relevant here? My magic mirror says, that problem is that OP invoke PowerShell from C# program, but forget to implement `PSHost`.

Comment: @itsme86 is correct, sorry for not being explicit, I saw an answer on another post, but I tried everything , "-force", "-confirm:$false" nothing seems to work. So I posted actual PoS that's being hit by this error

Comment: @PinoyDev You have following options: remove `Write-Host`, upgrade to PowerShell v5, implement PowerShell host, which would know how to `Write-Host`.

Comment: oh ok. thank you @PetSerAl, I will have to try that.

Comment: it worked! @PetSerAl I had to replace it with write-output